# Is pureScale and HADR available on DB2 Community edition?

Tags: db2, high-availability

Is pureScale and HADR available on the free DB2 Community edition?

Answer (score 2):

Yes both are available subject to limitations.

Please refer to the documentation at the link below for the defininitions and the limitations, and feature comparison.

Functionality in Db2 product editions and Db2 offerings

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=editions-functionality-in-db2-product-db2-offerings#r0053238__note-pureScale

Comment: Ok so since the free edition has a limit of 4 cores, the DBs would be added together for that count. Even though they are not all active at the same time?

Comment: @LinuxMan1820, the doc only mentions Purescale and DPF as exceptions: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=editions-db2-database-product-offerings (See Db2 Community Edition), so my guess would be that you can use 4 cores for each.

Comment: When it comes to HADR that is

Comment: "Db2 Community Edition is restricted to a maximum of 4 virtual processor cores and 16 GB of instance memory. These restrictions apply to each physical or virtual server unless they are deployed in a pureScale or DPF cluster. In these instances, the restrictions apply to the entire cluster."

Does this mean I would be limited to two 2-core nodes?